# How could I fix my create action, using AJAX, nested attributes and jQuery in Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I managed to tangle myself in a really silly situation using AJAX and jQuery in Rails 4. I'm using nested attributes and currently trying to do the create action via AJAX.

With the following setup I'm able to create a new idea via AJAX, but it displays the idea on every project. When I reload the page, it shows correctly just the given idea per project, but the AJAX view is incorrect first.

Here is my projects index.html.erb view:

```
 <% @projects.each do |project| %>

    <p><%= project.name %></p>

    <ul class="postis">
        <%= render partial: "idea", collection: project.ideas %>
    </ul>

    <%= form_for([project, project.ideas.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
       <p><%= f.text_area :description %></p>
       <p><%= button_tag '', :class => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %></p>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

_idea.html.erb partial under the Projects view folder:

```
       <li><%= idea.description %></li>
```

I also have a _silly.html.erb partial under the Ideas view folder:

```
       <li><%= @idea.description %></li>
```

ideas_controller.rb

```
def create
    @idea = @project.ideas.new(idea_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @idea.save
            format.html {redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            render.html {render :new}
            render.js
        end
    end
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :projects do
   resources :ideas 
 end
```

Here is my Create.js.erb.

```
$('.postis').append("<%= j render("silly") %>")
$(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
```

My projects_controller.rb index is:

```
 def index
    @projects = Project.all
 end
```

I tried some options, for example if I try to render the idea partial in my Create.js.erb, e.g.:

```
$('.postis').append("<%= j render("projects/idea") %>")
$(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
```

I get an error: "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'idea'"

How could I get rid of the other partial and make the create action work with AJAX?

Comment: Have u tried it by putting it in an single quote `'projects/idea'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_idea.html.erb` partial uses `idea` variable, which you have to assign in `create.js.erb` file:

```
$('.postis').append("<%= j render("projects/idea", idea: @idea) %>")
```

**EDIT:**

To append created idea to correct ideas list, add project_id to `<ul>` element:

```
<ul id="<%= dom_id(project) %>" class="postis">
  <%= render project.ideas  %> <!-- shortcut for your code -->
</ul>
```

and modify the `create.js.erb` file again, now to use `id` instead of `class`:

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@idea.project)%>').append("<%= j render("projects/idea", idea: @idea) %>")
```

Comment: This almost works, but it still displays the idea on every project on the user interface. When I reload the page manually, it shows correctly. This is what Rails server shows: Started POST "/projects/42/ideas" Processing by IdeasController#create as JS ...
  Rendered projects/_idea.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered ideas/create.js.erb (1.6ms)
 Completed 200 OK

Comment: But I did manage to get rid of the other partial _silly.html.erb, so +1 for that! :) But still I'm confused why the idea is displayed initially on every project.